# Перехват события deactivate формы в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Как можно перехватить событие `deactivate` или `defocused` формы?

Пробовал так:

```
formMain.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_DEACTIVATED, event -> {
    System.out.println("WINDOW_DEACTIVATED");
});
```

Но первый параметр не принимается. Думаю, это из-за того что `WindowEvent` из пакета `java.awt.event.WindowEvent`, а в `javafx.stage.WindowEvent` нет константы `WINDOW_DEACTIVATED`.

Есть ли какие-то решения этой проблемы?

Comment: К сожалению так тоже не принимает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря что понимать под **deactivate**.

Для **defocused** можно повесить простой лисенер

```
formMain.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
     System.out.println("Window focused " + newValue);
}
);
```

Comment: Спасибо, данный вариант подходит как не когда!